# Inconsistent TokenStreamRewriter.InsertBefore() behavior with C "do-while();" statements

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to instrument C code with ANTLR listener mechanism. But I found some inconsistent behavior of the `TokenStreamRewriter.InsertBefore()` API with the C `do-while();` statement.

I have posted a detailed description as [ANTLR Issue #2252](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2252). So I won't duplicate it here.

Anyone met the same issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved. Turns out my assumption of the behavior of `InsertBefore/After()` is incorrect. I posted the detailed explanation to the [Issue #2252](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2252). Hope it can help someone as confused.